# CSS :first-line text-transform lowercase not working

Tags: css

The text-transform on :first-line does not work. I've already noticed that this is still a buggy error inside several browsers which has already been reported to Google Chrome 10 years ago...

What I need is a uppercase text for the complete H1 and a lowwercase text for the :first-line.

But maybe you guys can help met out with a proper work-around? I've already tried font-variant: small-caps but this ain't a beautiful solution that works for my design.

Check the snippet down here:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico');

h1 {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top 60px;
    font-family: arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
}

h1:first-line {
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: "Pacifico";
    color: #9ed1dd;
    line-height: 110px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h1>
```

Comment: As you can see in the code-snippet I''ve added the use of :first-line is working on a title (H1). Everything works fine, except for the text-transform function....

Comment: It works as expected, but because of the font-size only a small part fits on the first line. When the font-size is smaller, more words fit. See https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/bes9sp15/1/

Comment: what you want completely, I have not getten it. Do you want evaluate the first line as the font size10px?